# To express by means of a program that the loading of three models in an asynchronous way must be in a determined order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, three.js, data-synchronization

I currently have written a program which loads three models:

1) the first one is the foreground which is visible, it is called the '**original**' model:

[image]

2) the second one is the gray levels model which is not visible (it should hidden behind the foreground), it is called the '**segmented**' model:

[image]

3) the third one is other gray levels model, which starts with opacity 0, so it is invisible, and its mission is to be visible with the coloured segment, so it is the '**colors**' layer:

[image]

Currently I am facing the following difficulty:

Normally the execution order should be as stated previously: first loads original, then segmented and finally colors, as you would see in the console:

```
Has finished loading: original
Has finished loading: segmented
Has finished loading: colors
```

However sometimes, nearly 1 of each 5 times, it loads first the segmented, then the colors and finally the original, which produces that the program behaves unexpectedly:

```
Has finished loading: segmented
Has finished loading: colors
Has finished loading: original
```

Which produces that the segmented model which sould be invisible behind the foreground, now it is visible because is the first one loaded:

[image]

The code which orders to load the three models is:

SceneManager.js

```
createSceneSubjects(scene, IndexAtlas) {


    let isOriginalNrrd = true;
    const sceneSubjects = [
        new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'original')
    ];
    isOriginalNrrd = false;
    sceneSubjects.push(new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'segmented'));
    sceneSubjects.push(new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'colors'));
    return sceneSubjects;
}
```

Where each SceneSubject loads a model, and when the loading has succeeded we call onSuccess function to add it to the scene:

SceneSubject.js

```
export default class SceneSubject {
    constructor(scene, originalNrrd, IndexAtlas, name) {

        this.scene = scene;
        this.originalNrrd = originalNrrd;

        this.loader = new NRRDLoader();
        this.filename = this.getFilename(IndexAtlas, originalNrrd);

        this.volumesManager = new VolumesManager(this.loader);

        this.loader.load(this.filename, this.onSuccess.bind(this));

        this.name = name;


    }

    onSuccess(volume) {
        //z plane
        let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

        this.volumesManager.addVolumeSliceToMultiVolumeSlice(sliceZ, this.originalNrrd);

        this.handleLoadingSpinners();

        this.scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);

        console.log('Has finished loading:', this.name);


    }


    getFilename(IndexAtlas, originalNrrd) {

        if (partHasBeenChosenFromGalery()) {
            return getChoosenPartFromThePartClickedOnTheGallery();
        } else {
            return getChoosenPartFromSegmentClickedOnCoverPageURL();
        }


        function partHasBeenChosenFromGalery() {
            return window.partIndex != null;
        }

        function getChoosenPartFromThePartClickedOnTheGallery() {
            return originalNrrd ?
                IndexAtlas.getSubAtlasActual().subAtlas[window.partIndex].getNrrdVolumen().getOriginal()
                :
                IndexAtlas.getSubAtlasActual().subAtlas[window.partIndex].getNrrdVolumen().getSegmentado();
        }

        function getChoosenPartFromSegmentClickedOnCoverPageURL() {
            return originalNrrd ?
                IndexAtlas.getSubAtlasActual().getParteActual().getNrrdVolumen().getOriginal()
                :
                IndexAtlas.getSubAtlasActual().getParteActual().getNrrdVolumen().getSegmentado();
        }
    }


    handleLoadingSpinners() {
        if (isThereASpinner()) {
            removeSpinners();
        }

        function isThereASpinner() {
            return document.getElementsByClassName('spinner')[0];
        }

        function removeSpinners() {
            const spinners = document.getElementsByClassName('spinner');
            spinners[0].remove();
        }
    }

    update(time) {

    }


}
```

2) I have tried the following solution, to add timers to the second and third models loaded, the segmented and colors models, to defer their loading 10 milliseconds hoping that it would solve the issue:

```
createSceneSubjects(scene, IndexAtlas) {


        let isOriginalNrrd = true;
        const sceneSubjects = [
            new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'original')
        ];
        isOriginalNrrd = false;
        window.setTimeout(this.addSceneSubject
        (sceneSubjects, new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'segmented'),
            10));
        window.setTimeout(this.addSceneSubject
            (sceneSubjects, new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'colors')),
            10);
        return sceneSubjects;
    }

    addSceneSubject(sceneSubjects, sceneSubject) {
        sceneSubjects.push(sceneSubject);
    }
```

I have verified that the loading stills sometimes, like 1 of each 15 times, being unexpected as:

```
Has finished loading: segmented
Has finished loading: colors
Has finished loading: original
```

As you could see in the following picture:

[image]

3) Then I have tried the following solution, to create a global variable which would state when the original model has been succeeding loading, and then load the segmented and colors model as follows:

SceneManager.js

```
createSceneSubjects(scene, IndexAtlas) {


        let isOriginalNrrd = true;
        const sceneSubjects = [
            new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'original')
        ];
        isOriginalNrrd = false;

        if (window.hasOriginalLoaded) {
            this.addSceneSubject(sceneSubjects, new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'segmented'));
            this.addSceneSubject(sceneSubjects, new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'colors'));
        } else {
            this.addSceneSubject(sceneSubjects, new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'segmented'), 1000);
            this.addSceneSubject(sceneSubjects, new SceneSubject(scene, isOriginalNrrd, IndexAtlas, 'colors'), 1000);
        }


        return sceneSubjects;
    }
```

SceneSubject.js

```
export default class SceneSubject {
    constructor(scene, originalNrrd, IndexAtlas, name) {

        this.scene = scene;
        this.originalNrrd = originalNrrd;

        this.loader = new NRRDLoader();
        this.filename = this.getFilename(IndexAtlas, originalNrrd);

        this.volumesManager = new VolumesManager(this.loader);

        this.loader.load(this.filename, this.onSuccess.bind(this));

        this.name = name;


    }

    onSuccess(volume) {
        //z plane
        let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

        this.volumesManager.addVolumeSliceToMultiVolumeSlice(sliceZ, this.originalNrrd);

        this.handleLoadingSpinners();

        this.scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);

        console.log('Has finished loading:', this.name);

        if(this.name === 'original'){
            window.hasOriginalLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

And I have verified that the loading order is different like one of each 30 times, as follows:

```
Has finished loading: segmented
Has finished loading: colors
Has finished loading: original
```

Which generates:

[image]

**How could we express by program the condition to load the models 100% times in order?**

**Could you help me please?**

**Could you give me further links to reads and advices to follow to understand and fix this issue?**

I have also read:

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

The loader being used to load models in NRRD format is the following:

Example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_nrrd

Code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_nrrd.html

***Thank you for your time!***

Comment: Just in general: stay away from w3schools. Regarding your issue I'd look into [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or use the fact that a loader already has a success callback which you can use to request the next model.